# calculating the no of steps in insertion sort

Tags: c, insertion-sort

Here are the two versions of insertion sort, which I implement one from pseudo code and one directly. I want to know which version take more steps and space(even a little space is complex).

```
void insertion_sort(int a[], int n) {
    int key, i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        key = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && a[j] > key) {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = key;
    }       
}
```

and this one

```
insertion_sort(item s[], int n) {
  int i,j;
  for (i=1; i<n; i++) {
    j=i;
    while ((j>0) && (s[j] < s[j-1])) {
      swap(&s[j],&s[j-1]);
      j = j-1;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the sample sorting array a = {5, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3}. 
In my opinion 2nd version take more steps because it swaps number one by one, while the 1st one swaps greater numbers in the while loop and then swaps the smallest number. For example:
Upto index = 3, both version take equal steps, but when index = 4 comes i.e. to swap number 1, 2nd takes more steps than 1st. 
What do you think?

Comment: Both are O(n^2) time, O(1) space.

Comment: To be honest this question is not even worth a second of bothering. As it was mentioned they have same complexity in time and space. Also in practice few operations here or there don't make any significant difference.

Comment: @Andrey: suppose in 1st version, if I put the last line in while loop, then it takes 8 steps when it comes at index = 4, and excluding from while loop, it takes 5 steps. (5 steps like this a = {2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 3}, then 6 -> 1, then 5 -> 6, then 4 -> 5, then 2 -> 4 and finally 1 to index = 0), and in 8 steps which is for 2nd method, it swaps like this (1 -> 6 & and 6 -> 1), (5 -> 1 & 1 -> 5) and so on, total of taking 4 + 4 = 8 steps.

Comment: @ashish2expert your counting of steps doesn't really make much sense. You don't count number of instructions executed, nor number of CPU cycles, even not number of lines. Just some abstract *steps*. If you want really measure something meaningful, run a proper benchmarks and see if there is any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Number of steps" isn't a useful measure of anything.

Is a step a line? A statement? An expression? An assembler instruction? A CPU micro-op?

That is, your "steps" are transformed into assembler and then optimized, and the resulting instructions can have different (and potentially variable) runtime costs.

---

Sensible questions you might ask:

### 1 what is the *algorithmic complexity*?

As given in Rafe Kettler's comment and Arpit's answer, this is about how the algorithm scales as the input size grows

### 2 how does it *perform*

If you want to know which is faster (for some set of inputs), you should just measure it.

---

If you just want to know which performs *more swaps*, why not just write a `swap` function that increments a global counter every time it is called, and find out?

Comment: So, which one is more optimized

Comment: "optimized" for what? On which platform, under which compiler, and with what data? _Measure_ it!

Answer (score 1):

Number of swaps is the wrong term, you should count the number of assignments. swap() expands to three assignments and you therefore usually end up with more assignments in the second version without saving space (you may not have key in the second version, but swap() internally has something similar).

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are using two loops. so complexity `O(n*n)` time. Considering constant(1) time for all other statements.

Comment: This is the worst case complexity when all the elements are in reverse order. But if you calculate by hand, then you'll see 2nd version takes  additional 4 steps.

Comment: O(BigOh) means Max time or Upper bound which is worst case.

Comment: I know, but if you calculate no of swaps in both these then 1st one takes less steps

Comment: They both takes same steps if all are in decreasing order (which is worst case complexity). In this case they take O(n*n) time.

Comment: @ashish2expert "no of swaps in both" it should be equal for same array .

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze it line by line. I assume complexity of swap to be 3

a)
Computational complexity:
`3+(n-1)*(1+1+((n-1)/2)*(1+1+1)*(1+1)+1)=1+(n-1)*(3n)=3n^2-3n+1`
(We use n/2 because it appears to be the average of continuous worst case scenarios).

Memory:
3 ints, +1 (for loop)

b)
Computational complexity:2+(n-1)*(1+((n-1))/2(1+1+1)*(3+1))=2+(n-1)*(6n-5)=6n^2-11n+7

Memory:
2 ints, +cost of swap (most likely additional 1 integer)

Not counting the input memory, as it is the same in both cases.
Hope it helps.